# Is there a good alternative to gimp?

Tags: graphic-design

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but... my gimp is misbehaving and I need to create a detailed map.

Does anyone know a good alternative for gimp.

I'm not patient enough to work with inkscape.

I am using Lubuntu because the new Ubuntu is just... meh! Plus my old laptop can't make it work properly.

Thanks

Comment: What's exactly the problem with Gimp? What features would you need in your replacement?

Comment: @Alejandro I sort of love GIMP, it has most of the features I use most often, and does a good job of helping me create my designs, maps, edit photos... **but**  it sometimes misbehave. Yesterday and suddenly it was stopping me from doing shading on a map, then it begun not allowing me to work on some of the layers, the other day it got stuck on one of the brushes and wouldn't let me even reset its properties... I am just tired of needing to restart my laptop just to accomplish minor tasks. So I need something different.

Comment: You need to get very specific about what features you require to satisfy your particular needs. Provide this info as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling & reinstalling?

Comment: Just changed my whole system, maybe it'll work better on opensuse.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) it doesn't supply everything that GIMP does but may give you enough for what you are trying to do.

- Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- More about painting than photo editing

Answer (score 2):

I like [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/) and the sub-title says it all: "Painting Made Simple"